# How to fix setState warning in ReactJS for login page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a "Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op." on a login page. The first time I sign in there is no warning. If I log out and back in, the warning appears. If I do that again, 2 warnings appear, and then 3 and so on and so on. Upon research this probably due to having a callback function in the component, but I'm not really sure how to fix it. I'm using some old firebase code I copied from something else I wrote a while back, so that could also be the problem.

```
handleClick(){
    ...
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({redirect: true});
            console.log(user.uid);

        } else {
          // No user is signed in.
        }
      }.bind(this));




render() {
    if(this.state.redirect){
      console.log("Log in successful");
      return <Redirect to="/home" />
    }

    return (
      //sign in page
    )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `onAuthStateChanged` listener is being duplicated. Try this:

```js
this.auth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
  function(user) {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({ redirect: true });
      console.log(user.uid);
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
  }.bind(this)
);
```

Then unsubscribe when the component unmounts:

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  // Unsubscribe.
  this.auth();
}
```

Comment: This seems to have created an issue with a react router <Link to> on my login page. I have link to create an account and now when I click it the URL route changes but nothing happens until I click it again. Commenting out "this.auth()" fixes this issue, but of course brings back the original issue.

Comment: Any errors? Maybe try `if (this.auth) this.auth()`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your firebase callback runs regardless of your component state (mounted, not mounted, etc). 
You probably should deregister the callback on `componentWillUnmount` so it won't do stuff while the component isn't mounted.